# Highstock extra Y axis

Tags: axis, highcharts, extra

I have this JSON array. With this data, the graph is nicely plotted using Highcharts.

Now I'm trying to add extra Y axis (especially for the data1 serie).

> [{"name":"data1","data":[[1361574000000,121201],[1362006000000,122019],[1363388400000,122788],[1363820400000,123740],[1364511600000,124703],[1365112800000,125618],[1365544800000,126553],[1366063200000,127496],[1366668000000,128500],[1367272800000,129433],[1368309600000,130277],[1368655200000,131267],[1369346400000,132191],[1369864800000,133143]]},{"name":"data2","data":[[1361574000000,0],[1362006000000,40.6],[1363388400000,35.7],[1363820400000,41.24],[1364511600000,40.56],[1365112800000,38.96],[1365544800000,39.8],[1366063200000,40.58],[1366668000000,40.79],[1367272800000,38.06],[1368309600000,37.95],[1368655200000,41.31],[1369346400000,40.16],[1369864800000,38.79]]},{"name":"data3","data":[[1361574000000,0],[1362006000000,1.46],[1363388400000,1.42],[1363820400000,1.42],[1364511600000,1.37],[1365112800000,1.41],[1365544800000,1.41],[1366063200000,1.35],[1366668000000,1.45],[1367272800000,1.36],[1368309600000,1.36],[1368655200000,1.36],[1369346400000,1.37],[1369864800000,1.359]]},{"name":"data4","data":[[1361574000000,0],[1362006000000,59.276],[1363388400000,50.694],[1363820400000,58.5608],[1364511600000,55.5672],[1365112800000,54.9336],[1365544800000,56.118],[1366063200000,54.783],[1366668000000,59.1455],[1367272800000,51.7616],[1368309600000,51.612],[1368655200000,56.1816],[1369346400000,55.0192],[1369864800000,52.71561]]}]

However, I just can't manage to get the extra Y axis working. What is wrong with this code?

```
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('testdata.php', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            title : {
                text : 'test'
            },

            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'A'
                }
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'B'
                }
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'C'
                }
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'D'
                }
            }],

            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                name: 'A',
                data: data1,
                yAxis: 0,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'B',
                data: data2,
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'C',
                data: data3,
                yAxis: 2,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'D',
                data: data4,
                yAxis: 3,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
             }]
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In first series, you need to add i.e yAxis:1 where 1 i index of yAxis.

As a result serie will looks like:

```
[{"name":"data1",
yAxis:1,
"data":[[1361574000000,121201],[1362006000000,122019],[1363388400000,122788],[1363820400000,123740],[1364511600000,124703],[1365112800000,125618],[1365544800000,126553],[1366063200000,127496],[1366668000000,128500],[1367272800000,129433],[1368309600000,130277],[1368655200000,131267],[1369346400000,132191],[1369864800000,133143]]}]
```

Comment: I do not understand... Could you be more specific? Also, my data is not static (its stored in an SQLite3 DB). Thanks!